# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter" Error is getting while executing TestRunner.java file

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, extentreports

Here are dependencies which has used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
<groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- Extent Report >
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
<groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Selenium Dependancy-->
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image: Here are dependencies which has used]

If you are not including cucumber plugin with extent report then it works but when i have included cucumber plugin then it throws gherkin formatter error

Below error is displayed while using Plugin with Gherkin:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:171)
```

.
.
.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Reporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more



If you are not including cucumber plugin with extent report then it works but when i have included cucumber plugin then it throws gherkin formatter error
```

Please help me out for this.

Below is the cucumber class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:./Cucumber-Reports/Cucumber-Report.html","rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
    monochrome=true,
    features = {"./src/Features"},
    tags = {"@Regression"},
    glue={"stepDefinitions"},   
    dryRun = false,
    strict = true
)
```

Comment: Can you please share us your cucumber class.

Comment: Hi @SelçukAyhan, I have attached cucumber class code

Comment: @Shashi I am getting this error too. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Yes, For this issue u have to use info.cukes dependencies instead of io.cucumber.

Comment: I would like recommend use Allure report if u want use io.cucumber

Answer (score 0):

Your `extentreports` version is 2.41.2 and it can only works with version 3 or above.

Here is the dependency you should change the version :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version> //You should update it to 3 or above.
</dependency>
```

Comment: No luck. I have updated dependancies attached it. Please let me know if i need any modification

Comment: Sorry about it, hope you will find solution. @Shashi